# Passenger standalone fails to compile Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, debian, passenger

I restarted my server and since then Passenger is trying to install a new Nginx version which fails during compilation.

Any ideas highly appreciated. 
I'm looking for any ideas on how to fix the compilation problem or how to use an older passenger version.

```
`Installing Phusion Passenger Standalone...
[*************************                    ] Compiling Phusion Passenger...
*** ERROR: the following command failed:
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [g++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHAS_TR1_UNORDERED_MAP -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -ggdb -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -o /home/path/.passenger/standalone/4.0.5/support-x86_64-linux-gcc4.9.2-1002/libpassenger_common/Utils/MD5.o -c ext/common/Utils/MD5.cpp]
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5/build/cplusplus_support.rb:42:in 'run_compiler'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5/build/cplusplus_support.rb:52:in 'compile_cxx'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/common_library.rb:133:in 'block (2 levels) in define_category_tasks'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in 'call'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in 'block in execute'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in 'each'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in 'execute'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in 'mon_synchronize'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in 'block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in 'each'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in 'invoke_prerequisites'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in 'mon_synchronize'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in 'block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in 'each'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in 'invoke_prerequisites'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in 'mon_synchronize'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in 'invoke'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in 'invoke_task'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in 'block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in 'each'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in 'block in top_level'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in 'run_with_threads'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in 'top_level'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in 'block in run'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in 'standard_exception_handling'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in 'run'
/home/path/deploy/staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in '<top (required)>'
/home/path/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/bin/rake:19:in 'load'
/home/path/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/bin/rake:19:in '<main>'
/home/path/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in 'eval'
/home/path/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in '<main>'
Tasks: TOP => nginx_without_native_support => /home/path/.passenger/standalone/4.0.5/support-x86_64-linux-gcc4.9.2-1002/PassengerHelperAgent => /home/xxx/.passenger/standalone/4.0.5/support-x86_64-linux-gcc4.9.2-1002/libpassenger_common/Utils/MD5.o`
```

**--Update--**

I got an older version of passenger working by specifying the passenger version in my gemfile.